# DataGridTextColumn's "TextBox" styling isn't consistent with its "TextBlock"

Tags: wpf, textbox, datagridtextcolumn

I'm having trouble styling the TextBox that's used for editing in a DataGridTextColumn.  A bit of background on this column:

- it's bound to a property called 'Top' (numeric value)
- there is a property called "ShowAll" used as a trigger to disable the column
- if the column is enabled, I want the look and feel of the TextBox to match that of the TextBlock (right aligned, centered vertically).

The cell looks perfect in non-edit mode.

*(apologies for the lack of pictures, but Stackoverflow requires 10 reputation points before pictures can be posted, which ironically causes one's early posts to be less effective; silly rule)*

If I leave out the DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle section (ie, if I go with the default editing style), when the cell receives focus the TextBox is upper-left aligned within the DataGridTextColumn:

[Default edit mode](http://i59.tinypic.com/2daj792.png)

I would like for the value being edited to remain right aligned and vertically centered.  But when I add the same two styles for EditingElementStyle that I did for ElementStyle, there is a blue background, and the textbox doesn't fill the cell:

[enter link description here](http://i59.tinypic.com/a0dnpc.png)

I've tried other setters such as HorizontalContentAlignment (value of Stretch), but no luck.  Here is my code:

```html
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Top" Binding="{Binding Path=Top}" Width="70">
 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
 <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
 <DataGridColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowAll}" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </DataGridColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue color might be one of the highlight key brushes from the SystemColors
(see the [List of SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.systemcolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

For filling the width of your cell, you maybe could try binding the width of the textbox to the cell like this:

```
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTextColumn}}}"/>
```

EDIT:
Funny enough, when testing your xaml changing the HorizontalAlignment to HorizontalContentAlignment worked for me :)

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />...
```

EDIT2 ;):
In fact you can overwrite the SystemColor Defaults adding this to your xaml to change the highlight effect:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
```

and additionally change the control key if necessary

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
```

be aware that the text brushes might behave differently and you might no be able to overwrite them.
For more details on that matter [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/03/25/109753.aspx) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I took your advice and also added a couple of additional properties to at least minimize the highlight key brush (which interestingly doesn't appear at all if I completely leave out the EditingElementStyle section).

Comment: Perfect - thanks again.  I'd upvote you but I don't have a high enough reputation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

More info regarding the solution which Ben suggested:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```